# My two paypal variables dont return the same value

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, webforms

I'm doing the Wingtip Toys sample from Microsoft and I'm having the following error:

```
 paypal Amount Total mismatch
```

This is happening because I have two variables, both decimal, one of them returns 2.94 and the other returns 294.

```
decimal paymentAmountOnCheckout = Convert.ToDecimal(Session["payment_amt"].ToString());
decimal paymentAmoutFromPayPal = Convert.ToDecimal(decoder["AMT"].ToString());
```

How can i set both of them with 2.94??

Comment: It can depends from Culture. You have to add some code and if possible the link to Wingtip Toys sample code.

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452365/paypal-amount-total-mismatch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [paypal Amount Total mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452365/paypal-amount-total-mismatch)

Comment: already fix it thx

Comment: So you can delete the duplicate post.